# Is there anyway to create a non-type template parameter for a class but not declare using <>?

Tags: c++

My original code looks like this:

```
class a{
...
char buff[10];
}
```

and im attempting to make this change to the code:

```
template <int N = 10>
class a{
...
char buff[N];
}
```

Is there any thing I can do to keep my existing code creating instances of class a like this:

```
a test;
```

instead of making the change to:

```
a<> test;
```

to get the default parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't instantiate a template without angle-brackets, and you can't give a type the same name as a template, so you can't do exactly what you want.

You could give the template a different name, and typedef `a` to the default-sized one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, don't make the class a template is the obvious answer - use something like:

```
class a {
   public:
      a( int n = 10 ) : buff(n) {}
   private:
      std::vector <char> buff;
};
```

Comment: Not really the same behaviour.

Comment: @DeadMG it is the same observed behaviour, which is all that matters in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Not in really good ways. You can typedef X to be X<> *in a different namespace*:

```
namespace lib {
template<int N=10>
struct X
{
 int t[N]; 
};
}
typedef lib::X<> X;
int main()
{
 X a;
 lib::X<20> b;
}
```

-- or --

```
template<int N=10>
struct X
{
 int t[N]; 
};
int main()
{
 typedef X<> X; // functions have their own namespace!
 X a;
 ::X<20> b;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Nope. The empty angle brackets are required.